# Trouble Getting Database to Update from DataAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, sqlconnection, dataadapter

I'm have trouble getting the SQL data adapter to update my code. I have confirmed that the method is being run, and the DataTable has new content on it at the time it runs.

```
    private void updateDatabase()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand someCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from employees where 0 = 1", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(someCommand))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees (UserName, Password, Name, Department, Manager, SSN, Salary) " +
                                                            "VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @Name, @Department, @Manager, @SSN, @Salary)", conn)) { da.InsertCommand = ins; }
                    using (SqlCommand del = new SqlCommand("DELETE Employees " +
                                                            "WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID", conn)) { da.DeleteCommand = del; }
                    using (SqlCommand upd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Employees " +
                                                            "SET UserName = @UserName, Password = @Password, Name = @Name, Department = @Department, Manager = @Manager, SSN = @SSN, Salary = @Salary " +
                                                            "WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID", conn)) { da.UpdateCommand = upd; }
                    da.InsertCommand = someCommand;
                    da.Update((DataTable) dataSQLGridView.DataSource);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any errors, or just 'nothing changes'?

Comment: @JosephWhitley do you have to use SqlDataAdapter?? Why not just user command.ExecuteNonQuery()??

Comment: Could you make/link an example? The code needs to take a DataTable and give the proper insert,delete,update statement corresponding to it..